# how do I solve this quadratic equation with a fraction?

Tags: quadratics

I seem to have trouble with quadratic equations when it comes to fractions and square roots.

$$
\frac{1}{x}+2x=3
$$
How do I solve this equation?

Comment: Hint: $x=0$ can not be a solution, so multiply the whole equation by $x$.

Comment: A general strategy is, as a first step, to clear any fractions by multiplying by the LCD: http://www.softschools.com/math/algebra/topics/clearing_equations_of_fractions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well mentioned by @dxiv in the comment, you can easily see that $x$ cannot be zero (otherwise in the expression on the left we will do something which is not permitted to do so [which I shall let you find]). So, you can multiply the equation by $x$.

On multiplying whole equation by $x$, you get $1+2x^{2}=3x$ $\implies 2x^2-3x+1=0$. On factorising, it becomes $(2x-1)(x-1)$. So, $x=1/2$ or $x=1$. As required.

Comment: Nice post; but You should say something about why you can multiply by x (that it's not zero).

Comment: You **can** multiply by x even when it is 0!  It just doesn't help solve the equation because then the equation reduces to "0= 0".

Comment: Thanks @amWhy, I have edited it now.

Comment: @user247327 no, because you'd have division by $0$ first, and you can't just multiply that by $0$ expecting anything times zero equals zero.

Answer (score 0):

Or, multiply by $\, y = x^{-1}$ to get $\ y^2-3y +2 = (y\!-\!2)(y\!-\!1)= 0\ $ so $\, x^{-1} = y = 2,1$